# How to pause powerpoint presentation?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, presentation

I am trying to write my own remote control in C# for powerpoint presentations, and I'm already able to go to next or previous slide, stop and play presentation. I want to be able to also pause a presentation. How do i do that?

Comment: In terms of PowerPoint (ie. if we leave the programming part out of it), what *exactly* do you mean by pause the presentation, and how do you accomplish this in PowerPoint today, keystrokes, menu items, etc.?

Comment: In powerpoint you can make presentation with slides that will be shown for fixed time span. You can pause this presentation by right-clicking on on a slide and choosing proper option.